# Can you pay more life than you have?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have 35 life, and I have [Lich's Mirror](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=174818%20), which

> If you would lose the game, instead shuffle your hand, your graveyard, and all permanents you own into your library, then draw seven cards and your life total becomes 20.

can I play [Aetherflux Reservoir](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=417765)?

> Pay 50 life: Aetherflux Reservoir deals 50 damage to target creature or player.

Would I be able to play Aetherflux Reservoir, use up 35 life, use Lich's Mirror to get back up to 20 and pay the last 15 life? Or would Lich's Mirror require me to shuffle the card back into my deck first? In which place could I use [Exquisite Archangel](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Exquisite+Archangel)?

> If you would lose the game, instead exile Exquisite Archangel and your life total becomes equal to your starting life total

Or would I just not be able to play this Aetherflux Reservoir in this manner at all?

If [Rhox Faithmender](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=279987)

> If you would gain life, you gain twice that much life instead.

is on the field when Lich's Mirror is played, do I get 40 life, or is he shuffled back into the deck first? Would I get 40 life if I used Exquisite Archangel?

If my opponent plays a card such as [Approach of the Second Sun](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=426706)

> If Approach of the Second Sun was cast from your hand and you've cast another spell named Approach of the Second Sun this game, you win the game.

for the second time, and I have Exquisite Archangel and Rhox Faithmender, and I have 8 life, do I exile Exquisite Archangel and get 20 life, 40 life, or 32 life?

What would happen if I had 30 life when Approach of the Second Sun was played and I exiled Exquisite Archangel? Would I be reduced to twenty life, or could I remain at 30 life?

Sorry for all of the questions. I am somewhat new to magic, and just got a deck, and was wondering about the new combos that I could do with them.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange!  The general policy on this site is to keep to 1 question per post.  Please [edit] your post to pare it down to one question, and consider posting your other question(s) separately.  (In this case, I would recommend cutting it before "If Rhox Faithmender...")

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot pay more life than you have.  From the [comprehensive rules](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Life) (emphasis mine):

> **118.4.** If a cost or effect allows a player to pay an amount of life greater than 0, the player may do so **only if his or her life total is greater than or equal to the amount of the payment.** If a player pays life, the payment is subtracted from his or her life total; in other words, the player loses that much life. (Players can always pay 0 life.)

You're not allowed to "split the cost" to pay part now and part later, either.  All costs must be payed in full before a spell or ability can be activated.<sup>[CR 117.3](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Cost)</sup>

In order to use Aetherflux Reservoir's ability, you have to have 50 life to pay the cost up front.